# Dynamical column which depends of the filling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of artists like this:

```
artistsList = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Kate", "headings": [ 'heading1', 'heading2' ] },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Alice", "headings": [ ] },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Mat", "headings": [ 'heading1' ] },
    .....
];
```

Also I have an object like this by default:

```
columns: {
    columnsList: [
        { 'id': 1, 'title': '---', 'artistsIds': [ ] }
    ],
    columnOrder: [ 1 ]
}
```

And I need to put artists into columns. 
I add all ids from artists array to artistsIds at columns object. After that I need to display artists.

For example column's height could be 500px maximum. But all this artist's list takes more place than 500px at high. This mean that I need to create next column and put lefted items into it. And I need to distribute an array of artists between them.

The number of column is dynamic and artists item could have different height. 
So I need to know how to control the filling of column which depend on items height, because height, as I anderstand, available after returnig in the end of component.

Here is my trying:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { DragDropContext, Draggable, Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import artists from 'artistsTest.js';
import './ArtistsTest.css';

class Artists extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            artists
        };
    }
    render() {
         return this.state.artists.columns.columnOrder.map((columnId) => {
        const column = this.state.artists.columns.columnsList[columnId - 1];
        const artists = column.artistsIds.map((artistId) => 
            this.state.artists.artistsList[artistId-1]);

        return <div className='column' ref={this.blockHeight} key={column.id}>
                    {artists.map((artist, index) => 
                        <div key={index} className='item'>
                            <div>
                                {artist.name}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
               </div>
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap at all? This seems like a great case for their [card columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns)

Comment: no, i'm not using bootstrap.
i made such structure to add react-beautiful-dnd library wich help drag&drop items in column in future